# How to Perform Statistical Two-Sided Test for Independence (on Proportion) in R?

Tags: r, sas, statistics, chi-squared

I am trying to compare two percentages/proportions for statistical significance in R, using a Chi-Square test. I am familiar with a SAS method for Chi Square in which I supply a dataset column for a numerator, another column for denominator, and a categorical variable to distinguish distributions (A/B).

However I am getting unexpected values in R using some examples sets. When I test two similar populations, with low sample sizes, I am getting p-values of (approximately) zero, where I would expect the p-values to be very high (~ 1).

My test set is below, where I went with sugar content in a batch of water: e.g. "does group A use the same ratio of sugar as group B?".  My actual problem is similar, where this isn't a pass-fail type test and the numerator and denominator values can vary wildly between samples (different sugar and/or water weights per sample). My first objective is to verify that I can get a high p-value from two similar sets. The next question is, at what sample size does the p-value become low enough to indicate significance?

```
        # CREATE 2 NEARLY-EQUAL DISTRIBUTIONS (EXPECTING HIGH P-VALUE FROM PROP.TEST)
    set.seed(108)
    group_A =  tibble(group = "A", sugar_lbs = rnorm(mean = 10, sd = 3, n = 50), batch_lbs = rnorm(mean = 30, sd = 6, n = 50))
    group_B =  tibble(group = "B", sugar_lbs = rnorm(mean = 10, sd = 3, n = 50), batch_lbs = rnorm(mean = 30, sd = 6, n = 50))
    batches <- rbind(group_A, group_B)
```

I then do a summarize to calculate the overall sugar percentage tendency between groups:

```
    # SUMMARY TOTALS
    totals <- batches %>%
        group_by(group) %>%
        summarize(batch_count = n(),
            batch_lbs_sum = sum(batch_lbs), 
            sugar_lbs_sum = sum(sugar_lbs),
            sugar_percent_overall = sugar_lbs_sum / batch_lbs_sum) %>%
        glimpse()
```

I then supply the sugar percentage between groups to a prop.test, expecting a high p-value

```
    # ADD P-VALUE & CONFIDENCE INTERVAL
    stats <- totals %>%
        rowwise() %>%
        summarize(p_val = prop.test(x = sugar_percent_overall, n =  batch_count, conf.level = 0.95, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value) %>%
        mutate(p_val = round(p_val, digits = 3)) %>%
        mutate(conf_level = 1 - p_val) %>%
        select(p_val, conf_level) %>%
        glimpse()
    
    # FINAL SUMMARY TABLE
    cbind(totals, stats) %>%
        glimpse()
```

Unforunately the final table gives me a p-value of 0, suggesting the two nearly-identical sets are independent/different. Shouldn't I get a p-value of ~1?

```
    Observations: 2
    Variables: 7
    $ group                 <chr> "A", "B"
    $ batch_count           <int> 50, 50
    $ batch_lbs_sum         <dbl> 1475.579, 1475.547
    $ sugar_lbs_sum         <dbl> 495.4983, 484.6928
    $ sugar_percent_overall <dbl> 0.3357992, 0.3284833
    $ p_val                 <dbl> 0, 0
    $ conf_level            <dbl> 1, 1
```

From another angle, I also tried to compare the recommended sample size from power.prop.test with an actual prop.test using this recommended sample size. This gave me the reverse problem -- I was a expecting low p-value, since I am using the recommended sample size, but instead get a p-value of ~1.

```
    # COMPARE PROP.TEST NEEDED COUNTS WITH AN ACTUAL PROP.TEXT
    power.prop.test(p1 = 0.33, p2 = 0.34, sig.level = 0.10, power = 0.80, alternative = "two.sided") ## n = 38154
    prop.test(x = c(0.33, 0.34), n = c(38154, 38154), conf.level = 0.90, alternative = "two.sided") ## p = 1 -- shouldn't p be < 0.10?
```

Am I using prop.test wrong or am I misinterpreting something? Ideally, I would prefer to skip the summarize step and simply supply the dataframe, the numerator column 'sugar_lbs', and the denominator 'batch_lbs' as I do in SAS -- is this possible in R?

(Apologies for any formatting issues as I'm new to posting)

## ---------------------------------

## EDIT - EXAMPLE WITH ONLY PROPORTIONS & SAMPLE SIZE

I think my choice of using normal distributions may have distracted from the original question. I found an example that gets to the heart of what I was trying to ask, which is how to use prop test given only a proportion/percentage and the sample size. Instead of `city_percent` and `city_total` below, I could simply rename these to `sugar_percent` and `batch_lbs`. I think this reference answers my question, where prop.test appears to be the correct test to use.

My actual problem has an extremely non-normal distribution, but is not easily replicated via code.

## STANFORD EXAMPLE (pages 37-50)

## - https://web.stanford.edu/class/psych10/schedule/P10_W7L1

```
    df <- tibble(city = c("Atlanta", "Chicago", "NY", "SF"), washed = c(1175, 1329, 1169, 1521), not_washed = c(413, 180, 334, 215)) %>%
        mutate(city_total = washed + not_washed,
            city_percent = washed / city_total) %>%
        select(-washed, -not_washed) %>%
        glimpse()
    
    # STANFORD CALCULATION (p = 7.712265e-35)
    pchisq(161.74, df = 3, lower.tail = FALSE) 
    
    # PROP TEST VERSION (SAME RESULT, p = 7.712265e-35)
    prop.test(x = df$city_percent * df$city_total, n = df$city_total, alternative = "two.sided", conf.level = 0.95)$p.value
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `prop.test` says:

> Usage `prop.test(x, n, p = NULL,
>             alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),
>             conf.level = 0.95, correct = TRUE)`
>
> Arguments
>
> `x`   **a vector of counts of successes**, a one-dimensional table with two entries, or a
>   two-dimensional table (or matrix) with 2 columns, giving the counts of
>   successes and failures, respectively.
>
> `n`    a vector of counts of trials; ignored if x is a matrix or a table.

So if you want a "correct" test, you would have to use `sugar_lbs_sum` as the `x` instead of `sugar_percent_overall`. You should still receive some kind of warning that the `x` is non-integral, but that's not my major concern.

But from a *statistical* perspective this is the complete wrong way of doing things. You are directly causing spurious correlation for a testing of difference between two quantities by dividing by their sum arbitrarily. If the samples (`sugar_lbs_sum`) are independent, but you divide by their sums, you have made the ratios dependent. This violates the assumptions of the statistical test in a critical way. Kronmal 1993 "Spurious correlation and the fallacy of the ratio" covers this.

The data you generated are independent normal, so don't sum them, rather test for a difference with the t-test.

Comment: @Jim apples and oranges. Presence/absence of lung disease is binary. Your sugar data is continuous, normally distributed. Also the respective proportions are calculated from the $n$ in either group, not overall.

Comment: The reason I'm not using a t-test to compare the means of `sugar_lbs_sum` is that one of the groups can possibly be  a "double-batch". The question in other words is: "did the two groups use the same recipe?" 

I think this [link](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/chi-square-test-proportions/) is along the lines of what I'm trying to do. The suggestion is that multiply the percentage by the total counts per group. This gives me a p_value of 0.02, which looks a bit more reasonable, but still not sure if technically correct.

Comment: @Jim if you write the algebra, it's clear that creating a proportion doesn't solve this "double batch" problem. Makes it worse if anything. If you have data errors, you have to correct them to apply statistical tests and getting expected output. If you *know* which batches are double, divide them by 2 or exclude.

Comment: Agree with @AdamO the distribution generated is normal. Using a binomial based test is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The Stanford link I added to my original post answered my question. I modified the Stanford example to simply rename the variables from `city` to `group`, and `washed` counts to `sugar_lbs`. I also doubled one batch, (or comparing a small versus large city). I now get the expected high p-value (0.65) indicating that there is no statistical significance that the proportions are different.

When I add more groups (for more degrees of freedom) and continue to vary batch sizes proportionally, I continue to get high p-values as expected, confirming the recipe is the same. If I modify the sugar percent of any one group, the p-value immediately drops to zero indicating one of the groups is different, as expected.

Finally, when doing the prop.text within a 'dplyr' pipe, I found I should not have used the rowwise() step, which causes my p-values to fall to zero. Removing this step gives the correct p-value. The only downside is that I don't yet know **which** group is different until I compare only 2 groups at a time iteratively.

```
#---------------------------------------------------------
# STANFORD EXAMPLE - MODIFIED TO SUGAR & ONE DOUBLE BATCHED
#--------------------------------------------------------
df <- tibble(group = c("A", "B"), sugar_lbs = c(495.5, 484.7), water_lbs = c(1475.6 - 495.5, 1475.6 - 484.7)) %>%
    mutate(sugar_lbs = ifelse(group == "B", sugar_lbs * 2, sugar_lbs),
        water_lbs = ifelse(group == "B", water_lbs * 2, water_lbs)) %>%
    mutate(batch_lbs = sugar_lbs + water_lbs,
        sugar_percent = sugar_lbs / batch_lbs) %>%
    glimpse()

sugar_ratio_all <- sum(df$sugar_lbs) / (sum(df$sugar_lbs) + sum(df$water_lbs))
water_ratio_all <- sum(df$water_lbs) / (sum(df$sugar_lbs) + sum(df$water_lbs))
dof <- (2 - 1) * (length(df$group) - 1)

df <- df %>%
    mutate(sugar_expected = (sugar_lbs + water_lbs) * sugar_ratio_all,
        water_expected = (sugar_lbs + water_lbs) * water_ratio_all) %>%
    mutate(sugar_chi_sq = (sugar_lbs - sugar_expected)^2 / sugar_expected,
        water_chi_sq = (water_lbs - water_expected)^2 / water_expected) %>%
    glimpse()

q <- sum(df$sugar_chi_sq) + sum(df$water_chi_sq)

# STANFORD CALCULATION
pchisq(q, df = dof, lower.tail = F)

# PROP TEST VERSION (SAME RESULT)
prop.test(x = df$sugar_percent * df$batch_lbs, n = df$batch_lbs, alternative = "two.sided", conf.level = 0.95)$p.value
```